# Application cannot locate image resource, using CommonControls

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

As a part of my application I have buttons with images. I use the WPF_CommonControls library. I have a folder called Images in my project where I store all the pictures. I set up the grid like this:

```
<Grid>
      <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListboxItemStyle}" IsTabStop="True" Margin="6,6,6,62" Name="lvJusticePersonnel" TabIndex="7" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single"/>
      <CommonControls:ccBilingualButton Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="0" Cursor="Hand" Height="50.043" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,6" Name="btnEditJustPerson" TabIndex="9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" ImageSource="imgEdit.png" LabelEnglish="Edit" LabelFrench="Edit" FontWeight="Bold" ImageLocation="Top" Foreground="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="DarkGreen" BorderThickness="1" />
      <CommonControls:ccBilingualButton Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="0" Cursor="Hand" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,86,6" Name="btnAddJustPerson" TabIndex="8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" LabelEnglish="Add" LabelFrench="Add" ImageSource="imgAdd.png" FontWeight="Bold" ImageLocation="Top" Foreground="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" />
</Grid>
```

But when I try to use this the lines starting with CommonControls:ccBilingualButton get underlined in blue and I get the messages "cannot locate resource 'images/imgedit.png'." and "cannot locate resource 'images/imgadd.png'."

These images both are contained in the Images folder and can be opened. I've gone through the object browser and tried to open the ccBilingualButton class, but it does not open.

Also, I've tried searching around and there's practically nothing written about this class on the internet.

The problem lies in the component: `ImageSource="imgEdit.png"`

Any suggestions for fixing this error?

Update: The debugger runs fine and the images show up in the application when I'm running it. The problem is I can't publish it and install it on other computers while these errors exist.

Update 2: Looking at the project file, I see that all the images are included

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\imgAdd.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgCancel.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgClock.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgClock_Small.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgConfirm.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgDelete.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgEdit.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgError.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgHelp.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgInfo.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgProject-Small.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgReports.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgSearch.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgUser.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\imgWarning.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But I've noticed that the slashes in the itemGroup are the opposite from the error message I'm getting. The error message is `Cannot locate resource 'images/imgEdit.png'` but the resource include uses `\`.

Now, if I try to change the resource include slash, it raises more errors since using `/`for a path isn't correct.

So, I need to change the path string that the xaml line is using, i.e. the 'Cannot locate resource' line, however I do not know where it is located.

If anyone else has had this issue, I'd love to hear some ideas.

Comment: Make sure the images are referenced correctly in the project file.  They should be included as something like `<Resource Include="Images\imgEdit.png"/>`.

Comment: So my project file has lots of folders in it, views, images and such. Is there a specific place I should put this line of code? A universal file that all projects have?

Comment: This would be in the .vbproj file, and then, only if it's the old format that explicitly states everything in the project file.  If it's the new format where it's assumed that everything in the folder is part of the project, I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: I'm using VS2012, and my solution explorer has the project file as an expandable menu. I open it and it lists all my folders and files. I'm not sure if that's the old format or the new.

Comment: If it's VS2012, I'm pretty sure it's the old format.  In order to do something with the project file, you'll need to either open it with something other than Visual Studio (e.g. Notepad) or you'll need to unload the project in the solution then load it as XML in Visual Studio (there should be a dropdown on the "Open" button in the file dialog with "Open as..." to do this).

Comment: Unloading it and clicking "edit project.vbproj" allowed me to open the file to see all the resource include statements. All the images appear to be included, but I'll look into it a bit further to find out if there's any issues.

Comment: It seems the image source is using a bad path, one that uses a ```/``` instead of ```\```. Not sure why, has anyone ever seen this happen?

Comment: I generally hand-code my xaml, so I'm no help.